# How to Place Text Over a Parallax Scrolling Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a heading over the image on my website.  Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/o3942ppa/1/

I tried to fix the problem by creating a heading with id header such as:

```
<h2 id="header">Text</h2>
```

and style it absolutely with a z-index to ensure it displays on top like:

```
#header{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

I was assuming that this would result in positioning the title on top of all over elements, positioned from the edge of the document. However, I didn't get the desired result.  How would I go about doing this?  Also, I read last night that it's generally better to using floats than positioning.  Not sure if that applies in this case, or if it's true at all.  I would appreciate if someone could weigh in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to adjust the structure of your HTML content so you `#header` is before your `.parallax`. Using your desired style:

```css
.parallax{
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/349608/pexels-photo-349608.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
    min-height: 500px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}

#header{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}

.text-box{
 height: 600px;
 padding: 50px;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .parallax {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<title>Bootstrap Default Template</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1 id="header">Text</h1>
<div class="parallax"></div>
<div class="col-lg-12 text-box text-center">
<h1>Restauraunt Heading</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to simply put your `h1` into a paralax div...

```css
.parallax{
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/349608/pexels-photo-349608.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
    min-height: 500px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;

}
.text-box{
 height: 600px;
 padding: 50px;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .parallax {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
#header{
 position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<title>Bootstrap Default Template</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="parallax"><h1 id="header">Text</h1></div>
<div class="col-lg-12 text-box text-center">
<h1>Restauraunt Heading</h1>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.paralax` class also needs to have added position attribute as `relative` or `absolute`.  You can also set `z-index: 0`

Ah, and `z-index: 1` is enough for header :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`.  Absolute positioning will place the element relative to its parent container.  Fixed positioning positions it relative to the document body.  Relative positioning (`position: relative`) positions it relative to where it would naturally fall in the flow of the DOM.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/o3942ppa/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Img + Text +
On SaaS

```
title: {
display: "inline-block",
position: "relative", 
marginTop: "30px",
minHeight: "32px",
color: "#FFFFFF",
textDecoration: "none"
}

parallax: {
backgroundImage: 'url(/images/example.jpg)', 
height: "90vh",
maxHeight: "1000px",
overflow: "hidden",
position: "relative",
backgroundPosition: "center center",
backgroundSize: "cover",
margin: "0",
padding: "0",
border: "0",
display: "flex",
alignItems: "center"
},
```